# Rails authentication not reacting to wrong username or password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am building a rails app that requires a log in. I have only one user set up and anytime I enter an incorrect user or password, it does nothing but appends "utf8=✓&authenticity_token=TnSbSndhlfVfO6VLpeGLWgkCdrcXvMFD6gUVyCRax64%3D&email=&password=&commit=Submit" to the URL. I have it set up to say "Invalid username or password" but it's doing nothing. I need it to authenticate and direct the user to the next page. It's not taking me to the next page with the correct username and password either. It just appends that string to the URL and does nothing else. I am new to this so apologies if I'm not being clear enough. Here's my code:

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  attr_accessor :password
  before_save :encrypt_password

  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_uniqueness_of :email

  def self.authenticate(email, password)
      user = find_by_email(email)
      if user && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)
          user
      else
          nil
      end
  end

  def encrypt_password
      if password.present?
          self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
          self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
      end
  end
end
```

appplication_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  helper_method :current_user
  before_filter :require_login


  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

  def require_login
    unless current_user
      redirect_to log_in_path, :notice => "Please log in to access this page."
    end
  end
end
```

sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :require_login 

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
    if user
      session[:user_id] = user_id
      redirect_to stats_path, :notice => "Welcome"
    else 
      flash.now.alert = "Invalid email or password"
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged out"
  end
end
```

form view html

```
<h2 class="form-signin-heading">Log In</h2>
<form class="form-signin">
  <%= form_tag sessions_path do %>
      <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
      <%= content_tag :div, msg, class: name %>
  <% end %>

  <%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email], :placeholder => "Email address", :class => "form-control" %><br />

  <%= password_field_tag :password, params[:password], :placeholder => "Password", :class => "form-control" %><br />


  <%= submit_tag "Submit", :class => "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" %>
<% end %>
</form>
```

Comment: We will need your view code to go any further, as it seems to be problem with your form.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing the ERB in your view to display the flash message.  Example:

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| -%>
  <%= content_tag :div, msg, class: name %>
<% end -%>
```

See this [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash) for more details...

Comment: That's not it. I actually have that code in my application html file. What I am trying to say is that it does not even redirect to the page when the correct credentials are entered. It does nothing in either scenario except appends that string to the URL.